# the image getting from webrtc is reversed, why?

Tags: video, easyrtc

I established a video chat by EasyRTC, with it's demo program. I can talk with another user and see the image from another user in the chat, but the all the image is reversed. how does this happen?

Comment: the image is just like the reflection in the mirror.

Answer (score 2):

You should mirror the image with CSS. Check the tutorial from W3Schools:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_flip_image.asp